# CKEditor instanceReady not working in Eclipse Nebula

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, eclipse-rcp, nebula

I am trying to use embedded CKEditor through [Eclilpse Nebula](https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/richtext/richtext.php) in a SWT control.
It uses CKEditor through in-build browser engine in Eclipse RCP. The control tries to initialize CKEditor in a Simple HTML textarea in a HTML page by using *startupFocus* of CKEdior, which fails to invoke.
It doesn't work consistently,works in one machine but not in other. Following is the code snippet from the Nebula class, please point me in right direction why it's not working always. Thanks in advance.

```html
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', 
                  {
                   startupFocus : true,
                   on: {
                    'instanceReady'  : function(event) { 
                     //maximize the editor after the editor instance is ready
                     maximizeEditorHeight(); 
                     
                     event.editor.on('resize', function(resizeEvent) { 
          if ((prevHeight == null) || prevHeight != resizeEvent.editor.container.$.clientHeight) {
           prevHeight = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.container.$.clientHeight;
           
           if (!mouseDown) {
            // if the resize is trigger by an external event, 
            // e.g. toolbar expand/collapse
            maximizeEditorHeight();
           }
           
           if (resizeCallbackEnabled) {
            resizeParentContainer();
           }
          }
          else if (prevHeight == CKEDITOR.instances.editor.container.$.clientHeight) {
           prevHeight = null;
          }
         });
                    },
                    //notify the FocusListener
                    'focus'    : function() { focusIn(); },
                    'blur'    : function() { focusOut(); },
                    //notify the ModifyListener
                    'change'    : function() { textModified(); },
                    //ensure the key pressed event is fired if Enter is pressed
                    'key'    : function(event) { event.data.preventDefault(false); },
                    //notify the KeyListener
                    'contentDom'  : function() {
                        this.document.on('keydown', function(evt) {
                         if (evt.data.$.ctrlKey && evt.data.getKey() == 70) {
                          //prevent opening of browser find dialog on CTRL + F
                          evt.data.preventDefault(false);
                          //open the ckeditor find and replace dialog
                          CKEDITOR.instances.editor.execCommand('find')
                         }
                         else if (evt.data.$.ctrlKey && evt.data.getKey() == 72) {
                          evt.data.preventDefault(false);
                          //open the ckeditor find and replace dialog
                          CKEDITOR.instances.editor.execCommand('replace')
                         }
                         
                            keyPressed(evt.data.getKey(), evt.data.getKeystroke());
                        });
                        this.document.on('keyup', function(evt) {
                            keyReleased(evt.data.getKey(), evt.data.getKeystroke());
                        });
                    }
                   }
                  });
```

Comment: I can not answer that question without further information. "works in one machine but not in other" is to unspecific. What doesn't work? What is the difference between the two machines/environments? Does it not work in your application or when started from the IDE? What IDE do you use? What environment (Win/Linux/Mac)? Typically it is a browser issue as  startupFocus is a ckeditor feature. So you could also try to check if ckeditor in general works on "the other machine"

Comment: Apologies for missing information,                                                              Both the machines have Win7, Eclipse 3.5, added the control in an Eclipse RCP, running from Eclipse. Both the machines have same version of IE and settings seem to be same. startupFocus is only for setting focus in the control. Even if we remove that part the CHKEDITOR.replace fails with only showing the textArea. Still not able to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Eclipse 3.5? You need at least Luna

Comment: I wish, I could do it on that, but our target environment in production is still on that. But, it's working in a machine.

Comment: Then the one machine doesn't have the target environment activated. Luna is required because of issues with the SWT Browser widget in prior versions.

Comment: Hi, both the machines have same target platform set. Again, interestingly I tried to run the same code in Eclipse Luna, and getting the same error. A correction to my previous statement, the original environment runs on Eclipse 3.7 (not 3.5 as I said before). Seems like something else making this fail.

Comment: The Nebula RichText bundle has a dependency to org.eclipse.swt;bundle-version="3.103.0". This is not available in Eclipse versions prior 4.4. If you have a target like Eclipse 3.7 the org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.richtext bundle should not even start. If it does, your target is broken. If you have that SWT version in your runtime somehow, it can only be the browser that is different.

Comment: Thank you for your input, you are right. It's working after I upgrade to 4.4 (with correct target platform). But I am trying to make it work in a jar file rather than in a directory. do you think that's going to work?

Comment: To add a closure to the original problem/discussion, the HTML code didn't work in pre-Eclipse 4.4 browser, because the old browser couldn't parse the comments added to HTML page for some reason. But it works perfectly in Eclipse 4.4 +. Thanks again for the great widget, its really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No because the HTML templates are referencing the js libraries and I couldn't find a way to specify those references within a jar. If you have an idea to solve that, feel free to contribute.